# Mezzanine 404 and 500 errors template not overriding

Tags: django, error-handling, mezzanine, custom-error-pages, errortemplate

I'm working with Mezzanine and want to override the generic Django 404 and 500 page template. I copied the errors folder into:

```
my_theme/templates/errors
```

the 404.html and 500.html templates inside errors should override the generic template but they do not... I tried to copy both files also directly into the /templates folder and is not working.

Comment: I don't know anything about themes, but I suspect your templates directory isn't in the search path. I'd take a look at your template settings.

Comment: thanks but I don't think this is the case since I have other files in the same templates directory and they are correctly overriding the templates...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Mezzanine are you using? In older versions, the template path should be my_theme/templates/ in stead of my_theme/templates/errors/ . 
See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/5N94Q33uwvc

In addition, did you define DIRS in your settings? Like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates")
        ],
    ...
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#configuration